# Unable to set custom timestamp xticks in seaborn lineplot [python]

Tags: python, datetime, seaborn, strftime

My dataframe looks like this:
[image]

We see category values for a given Date/Time timestamp, showing year, month, day, and the time.

Plotted as a lineplot in seaborn, the x-axis looks like this:
[image]

Here we see the Date/Time x-axis tick marks showing the month, day, and hour.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the Date/Time x-tick marks reformatted to just show the time, so starting at 00:00, with 6 total tick marks, and so for the whole study day, continuing with 04:00, 08:00, 12:00, 16:00, 20:00, 00:00.

I tried using this code to reset the date/time format:

```
x_dates = df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M').sort_values().unique()
dataplot.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates, rotation=45, ha='right')
```

And now my x-axis ticks look like this:
[image]

I do not understand why the hours go from 00:30 to 04:30. That means that my study only lasted until 4:30PM? I do not know if this is supposed to be military time or not. My study data lasts for 24 hours, so I do not understand why this code changes the data to end at 04:30.

And then I try to change the number of x-axis tick marks to 6 by adding:

```
dataplot.set_xticks(6)
```

But this just results in this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

How can I fix my date/time string formatting for my x-ticks so that it just shows the time throughout the 24-hour period, without the year, month, or day, and as 6-tick marks? I am using seaborn with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 9 xticks, so what you are doing in your code is replacing these with the first 9 values of your `x_dates`. Seaborn doesn't know how the `x_dates` relate to the plot you made, so it just takes the first 9 values.

If each study runs for exactly one day, the easiest way to solve this woudl be to create a new column containing just the time, then plot using that column.

`df['time'] = df['Date/Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: Thanks, that code worked, and I know see my x-axis tick labels formed as just the hour and minute, which is what I want. Though there are now 48 tick marks, showing a tick mark at each half-hour interval. Is there an argument I can add to my plotting line that specifies I only want to see 6 of those tick marks throughout the 24-hour period? I understand that I erroneously only specified to take the first 6 timestamp tick marks, rather than showing 6 timestamp tick marks spaced throughout the whole 24-hour period.